# Parse SQL Server Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I used SSIS and [SharePointListAdapters][1]
[1]: http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases
to import data from my SharePoint 2010 list and put it into SQL Server 2008 table. TThere are roughly 500 rows of data. Now the challenge is to parse data appropriately. I have a couple of columns that have html tags around them.

For e.g., Column Project Desc has data like
Project Desc

```html
<div class="ExternalClass914BB5DA5CB142EB854C739EAACEE3BB">
    <div>Import Data from SharePoint list to Database.
    </div>
</div>
```

On googling, I found the functio below. It works as expected. My questions is how do I edit this function to take the column name called Project Desc as a parameter so that all of the data in that particular column will have html tags discarded.

```sql
create function dbo.StripHTML( @text varchar(max) ) returns varchar(max) as 
begin 
    declare @textXML xml 
    declare @result varchar(max) 
    set @textXML = @text; 
    with doc(contents) as 
    ( 
        select chunks.chunk.query('.') from @textXML.nodes('/') as chunks(chunk) 
    ) 
    select @result = contents.value('.', 'varchar(max)') from doc 
    return @result 
end 
go 
select dbo.StripHTML('<div class="ExternalClassB1D90504EAFF42BE8A8056E686F4E195"> <div>Import Data from SharePoint list to Database.</div></div>')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've created the function, you just use it as if it was a normal field in a table, and put the source table and field in the place that the parameter goes...

```
SELECT
  dbo.StripHTML( yourTable.yourColumn ) AS yourResults
FROM
  yourTable
```

*(You don't edit the function, you just supply it with data from your table.)*

Comment: Thanks Dems. That was so simple. Thanks a lot. :) I can vote your answer in 4 mins. So I will see your vote in few mins. :)

Answer (score 1):

SQL and T-SQL have no means to parse HTML. Do not confuse HTML with XML...

You can use something like [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse HTML from managed code, be it in your SSIS package or as a SQLCLR deployed function.

Comment: He is not trying to parse HTML, he is stripping HTML tags from column data. Did you try the function? It works fine.

Comment: The function works fine iff your html tags are well formed. If your column has data like <div>Training should consist of:<br />1.&nbsp;Written material<br />2.&nbsp;Live meetings<br />3.&nbsp;1x1 where needed<br />4.&nbsp;Pod Casts (moved to new project)<br />5.&nbsp;Short video presentations to be loaded to Ed Services for field consumption (moved to new project)</div> <div>&nbsp;</div>. Then it fails saying xml parsing line 1:character 46, well formed check: undeclared entity...Any help?

Comment: HTML is **not** XML. *Well formed* HTML cannot be parsed as XML. Use an HTML parser.

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer on SQLServerCentral.com.  Because it's an iTVF (Inline Table Valued Function), it works faster than the function you're using right now. About twice as fast, as a matter of fact. Ref: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/FindPost1198135.aspx

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.StripHtmlTags2
        (@HtmlText XML )
RETURNS TABLE
     AS 
 RETURN
(
SELECT
    @HtmlText.value('(.)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS result
)
```